# Sending access token to my server and validating it,Google+ Login Android

Tags: android, validation, google-plus, access-token, google-signin

I have written this code to obtain **access token** from Google.

Now i want to send this access token to **my server** and then i want my server to send it to Google to **validate the token.**

I would be thankful if someone can give me working code or explain in detail how to do this?
I am implementing **Google+ Login** to my **Android App.**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    Log.v(TAG, "Connected. Yay!");

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
     @Override
       protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
              try {

                        String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                                mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            task.execute((Void) null);



}
```

Comment: You should probably start here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in
I think it explains pretty well, how to handle the signin flow.

Comment: I already did login. I could do that without any issue. Problem cam when handling access token.

Comment: @user3105927 have u already did this task can u pls share how u have managed access token at server side ?